# Single row not being validated in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm having a problem when I try to update a row in a datagridview. When I filter the list and receive one row back I want to update a value in the row, but the rowvalidating or rowvalidated are never called. When there are multiple rows I can update all rows, but it's still not working for the last row. So when there are no rows to go to after the enter is pressed.
When I tab through the row it will call the validating triggers, but I want to update from another element as well.
Does anyone as an idea?

Comment: You have to change the focus from the row. Try pressing tab or clicking somewhere else on the form and see if your events are called

Comment: When I tab through the row it is working, but I want to press Enter on the second of ten elements and then the validate needs to be called immediatelly.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is just a limitation of how the datagridview control works. Someone else might come along with an answer but I wouldn't hold your breath. You could try creating your own datagridviewcolumn with your own editing control which can keep track of changes but it's a bunch of wheel-reinventing...